# Datepicker dynamic declaration

Tags: jquery, grails, datepicker

I am developing web app in grails ,and I need some hints to resolve my problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.noConflict();
            $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy';
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
            $("input#startDate").datepicker();
            $("input#endDate").datepicker();
        });

    </script>
```

I have dynamic adding textfield with names **"startDate123"** and **"startDate23"** ,How to declare them like datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which you can use.. To add dynamic content you have to use live function. [Jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the alternate function which can solve this issue.

Another way you can solve it. Just add a class to you dynamic input. Let say calss="datepickert". so you can target you input for date picker like below. Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/201/

```
$('body').on('focus',"input#startDate, input#endDate, .datepickert", function(){
           $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Following code will work as a replacement of your existing code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.noConflict();
        $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy';
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
        $('body').on('focus',"input#startDate, input#endDate", function(){
           $(this).datepicker();
        });
    });
```

​

Comment: I have more then one datepickers.
Now datepicker appears, but when i confirm date he just fill first textfield .

Comment: Please check that you have add a class in input. its should work or go to the link http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/201/ and cross check with your code.